# How to add trainable variable in Python Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

I would like to add trainable parameter 'p' into my neural network model coded by Python tensorflow.
The parameter 'p' should range between 0 and 1. It can be ranged between 0 and 1, transformed by sigmoid function (e.g. p = 1/(1 + exp(-pi)) and in this case, values obtained from sigmoid function should be normally distributed.
Please let me know if you have any ideas to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do [tensorflow layers subclassing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) and add your `p` trainable variable through `self.add_weight` in your subclass.

Applying a sigmoid is one way to have your value between 0 and 1. Another way is through the `constraint` parameter of `self.add_weight` (It will clip your value between 0 and 1).